# Go, Google Cloud Appengine local package

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a package in Google Cloud project. How do I import my package in GOogle cloud?

```
foo   // my package
main.go
```

Then in `main.go`

How do I know what `gopath` I have in Google cloud console?

How would you import `foo` package from `main.go`?

Can I just do `import "foo"` in `main.go`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy your application, the goapp tool will bundle all the dependencies from your local GOPATH. If the app runs with your local GOPATH with `goapp serve`, it should run on appengine without additional work. See here for more information: https://blog.golang.org/the-app-engine-sdk-and-workspaces-gopath